# MVC:- Integration of mvc6.grid

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, mvcgrid.net

I want to integrate [mvc6.grid](http://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/Home/Installation), I followed the steps but getting error in view. Error "**'HtmlHelper< IEnumerable< SchemeMaster>>' does not contain a definition for 'Grid'**".

**Model:-**

```
 public partial class SchemeMaster
    {
        public int SchemeID { get; set; }
        public string SchemeName { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Createdby { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> Createddate { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
        public string city { get; set; }
        public Nullable<bool> Married { get; set; }
    }
```

**View :-**

```
    @model IEnumerable< MVC6_Grid_with_filters.Models.SchemeMaster>
    @using NonFactors.Mvc.Grid;
    @{
        Layout = null;
    }

    < link href="@Url.Content("~/Content/MvcGrid/mvc-grid.css")" rel="stylesheet" />
    < script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js">< /script>
    < script src="~/Scripts/MvcGrid/mvc-grid.js" type="text/javascript">< /script>

    @(Html
    .Grid(Model)
    .Build(columns =>
    {
        columns.Add(c => c.SchemeID).Titled("SchemeID");
        columns.Add(c => c.SchemeName).Titled("SchemeName");
        columns.Add(c => c.city).Titled("City Name");
        columns.Add(o => o.CompanyName).Titled("Company Name");
        columns.Add(c => c.Createddate, "Createddate").Titled("Date");
        columns.Add(c => c.Married).Titled("Married");
    })
    .Filterable()
    .Sortable()
    .Pageable()
    )
    <script>
        $('.mvc-grid').mvcgrid();
    </script>
```

Comment: What's your controller doing?  I suspect you're not passing the view with the right model.

Comment: I have the same problem. did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

My fix was to download mvc5.grid not 6 from nuget

Answer (score 0):

try adding `@using NonFactors.Mvc.Grid;` to  _ViewImports.cshtml

[mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/installation](https://mvc6-grid.azurewebsites.net/installation)