# While Create gridview using grid.Mvc6 showing error

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mvcgrid

In my project i try to add grid but its showing following error **'HtmlHelper>' does not contain a definition for 'Grid' and the best extension method overload 
'MvcGridExtensions.Grid(IHtmlHelper, IEnumerable)' requires a receiver of type 'IHtmlHelper'**

Code:

```
@model IEnumerable<SCM_MVC.Models.XXXXX>
@using NonFactors.Mvc.Grid;

        @(Html
                .Grid(Model)
                .Build(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Add(model => model.select).Titled("Name");
                    columns.Add(model => model.Surname).Titled("Surname");
                    columns.Add(model => model.MaritalStatus).Titled("Marital status");

                    columns.Add(model => model.Age).Titled("Age");
                    columns.Add(model => model.Birthday).Titled("Birthday").Formatted("{0:d}");
                    columns.Add(model => model.IsWorking).Titled("Employed");
                })
                .Empty("No data found")
                .Filterable()
                .Sortable()
                .Pageable()
        )
```

What am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem occurred because `NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6` package uses `IHtmlHelper` interface derived from `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering` namespace, while the grid should use `HtmlHelper` class from `System.Web.Mvc` namespace, hence the package is incompatible with MVC 5.

I suggest you to uninstall `NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6` package (since it designed for ASP.NET Core MVC) and use `NonFactors.Grid.Mvc5` package instead, by using Package Manager or console command:

```
Uninstall-Package NonFactors.Grid.Mvc6
Install-Package NonFactors.Grid.Mvc5
```

**Note:**

You can compare the contents of `Grid` extension method in [MVC 5](https://github.com/NonFactors/MVC5.Grid/blob/develop/src/Mvc.Grid.Core/Html/MvcGridExtensions.cs) and [Core MVC](https://github.com/NonFactors/MVC6.Grid/blob/develop/src/Mvc.Grid.Core/Html/MvcGridExtensions.cs) version, which proves different namespace usage.

Related issue:

[MVC:- Integration of mvc6.grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44451974/mvc-integration-of-mvc6-grid)

Comment: its working but i need checkbox column that's why i tried to move mvc6